# Is there a way to set relative start and end dates in SQL for last 4 complete months and current month to date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If applied to today, I want to return values for 1/10/19 through 25/02/20.

I am using the below currently, but wish to replace it with something that gives me 4 complete months and the current partial month

```
where DATEDIFF (day,[SubOrderCompletionDate],GETDATE()) between 0 and 180
```

Thanks

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.

Comment: What would you expect if today was 29 February 2020? 1 November 2019 to 29 February 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want complete months, just change this to:

```
where DATEDIFF(month, SubOrderCompletionDate, GETDATE()) between 0 and 3
```

`DATEDIFF()` counts the number of boundaries between two dates.  So, all days within a given calendar month return the same value.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` on the column could have some performance impacts here, as indexes won't be able to get used.

Comment: @Larnu . . . Absolutely true.  The OP is starting with `DATEDIFF()` though and did not mention performance.  I would NOT recommend `DATEDIFF()` under other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your statement literally, and therefore assumed that if today was 29 February 2020 you would want 1 November 2019 to 29 February 2020, not 1 October 2019 to 29 Feburary 2020:

```
SELECT * --This should be a column list, not *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE YT.SubOrderCompletionDate >= CASE WHEN EOMONTH(GETDATE()) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 3,0) ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 4,0) END
  AND YT.SubOrderCompletionDate <= GETDATE()
```

If that isn't the case, you just need `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 4,0)`, which will give you **5** months worth of data.